# How do I resolve error "TS2339: Property 'gauge' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'."

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am working on an ionic (version 4) application and I want to implement a custom gauge meter.

Since, I am new to jQuery I am not sure what exactly this error means.

I am using a jQuery plugin jquery-gauge.min.js which contains a method gauge() as shown below which works perfectly fine and normally in any web application.

```js
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})

export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    $('.gauge1').gauge({
      values: {
        0: '',
        10: '',
        20: '',
        30: '',
        40: '',
        50: '',
        60: '',
        70: '',
        80: 'Tier 1',
        90: 'Tier 2',
        100: 'Tier 3',
      },
      colors: {
        0: '#1aff1a',
        75.5: '#1aff1a',
        75.6: '#515e80',
        80: "#515e80",
        90: "#515e80",
      },
      angles: [
        180,
        360
      ],
      lineWidth: 10,
      arrowWidth: 0,
      arrowColor: '#ccc',
      value: 75.5
    });
  }
}
```

When I am implementing it on an ionic application it is throwing an error on line `$('.gauge').gauge({...})`

> error "TS2339: Property 'gauge' does not exist on type
> 'JQuery'

I have added jquery-gauge.min.js to the scripts in the `angular.json` file.

how can I resolve this error?

Comment: The error means that you have not added whatever library includes the `gauge()` method in to the page - or if you have, you've done it too late.

Comment: Just a guess: You are importing jquery but not the gauge plug in, that's why it's not available. It doesn't help if you load the plugin somewhere in your html page, you have to import it in your component file.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen you are right, the scenario is the same, and I have imported the jquery-gauge.min.js file to my component. shouldn't that help? or am I missing something?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please tell me what does it mean by 'done it late'?

Comment: I'd suggest to take some time to read about 'using JavaScript libs in TypeScript' - this can be tricky. In short: Most of the times, you have to help the typescript compiler and tell him about the surface of your lib (what functions are available, …) - for many libs you'll find predefined `@types/...` npm packages here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped sometimes, you have to provide some interfaces yourself.

Comment: Can you suggest a good link from where I can learn?

Comment: Why on the earth you would use Jquery with Angular/Ionic it is Anti Pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

use `jQuery('.gauge1').guage()` instead of `$('.gauge1').guage()`

Though I was new to jQuery, I didn't know how plugins may behave differently in different platforms (don't know why it exactly is) but, when I used the plugin in a .js file in a web app it worked by using `$('.guage').gauge()` but when I used it with ionic (or should say with .ts file) it required `jQuery('.guage').guage()` instead.

if anyone can explain why is that so. That will be grateful and helpful too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because this function is executed before the javascript with your gauge functionality is loaded.

Try to use the `ngAfterViewChecked()` lifecylce hook instead of the `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i have updated the question above. the compiler itself throws an error as `Property 'gauge' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'`.

Comment: try to cast it to any like this  `(<any>$(".gauge1")).gauge({})`

Comment: i've tried it but that just ignores the error at compile time and again comes back on runtime.

Comment: than create an interface in a new typescript file: `JQuery {   gauge():void; }`

You can use the cli to generate an interface: `ng generate interface JQuery` and then define the gauge method.

Comment: Please refer to updated question above suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

add this after the import statments

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

declare interface JQuery<HTMLElement> {
 gauge(...args): any;
}
...
```